# Resize constantly-changing image to fit size-changing screen, using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

I have a slideshow of images. It consists of several components:

- A black background
- A thin bar at the bottom of the screen which displays the current image's title (font size, and vertical dimensions in general, are not specified)
- A button to fullscreen the slideshow, or exit fullscreen if it already is, placed on that bottom bar
- A set of three images against the black background, taking up all available space while maintaining aspect ratio.

The images are placed on top of each other, shuffling between each other the roles of 'front', 'middle', and 'back'. The 'middle' image has opacity 1, the others have opacity 0. Every several seconds, a Javascript function designates the current 'back' image as the new 'middle' and the 'middle' image as the new 'front', changing their opacities accordingly (a CSS transition elapses over the following second, fading them into each other). The image that was formerly in 'front' is abandoned, and a new image is loaded into 'back' (via changing the `src` attribute directly).

I want these images to **fill the entirety of the screen space available to them** - everything but that bottom bar - **while maintaining their aspect ratios**. Whichever dimension is the lower bound on the image's size determines how large the image gets. In the meantime, the images need to be **centered in whichever dimension they're not filling** (so, horizontally centered for tall images, and vertically centered for wide images). Furthermore, the images need to **adapt to changing screen size**, preferably *as* the window size gets dragged.

I'm currently using a lengthy Javascript function to (1) find the available space by subtracting the height of the bottom bar from the screen height, (2) calculating the aspect ratio of the image, (3) comparing which dimension is the limiting factor, and (4) resizing and repositioning the element accordingly. This function gets triggered by the `window.onresize` event, and triggers manually whenever the image changes. However, when clicking-and-dragging to change the window size, the function gets called over and over. That's needlessly computationally intensive, and I'd like to have the size change in CSS instead if possible.

When I ran into this problem for the website that normally displays the images, my solution was `calc()`:

```
img.class {
    font-size:24pt; /* same font size as h1, which is the biggest title element. Used to calculate em */
    max-width: calc(100vw - 80px);  /* exactly enough to account for horizontal margins/padding */
    max-height: calc(100vh - 2em);  /* leave space for title but otherwise fill window */
}
```

The difference between that and this is that the *only* limiting factor was the screen size, and I knew exactly how large the other elements that were "supposed" to fit on screen were. The entire parent element was centered (and of course horizontal centering is easy), and since the screen was supposed to scroll, I didn't have to worry about vertical centering at all. So this solution is not reusable here, I don't think.

The intuitive solution I tried was to put horizontal and vertical alignment in a parent `<div>`, and set `max-width` and `max-height` in terms of percentages (since I can't get a different element's height in CSS to do math with):

```
#parent{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

img {
    transition: opacity 1s;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

But not only did this not center the images, it made them not appear at all! Removing `max-width` and `max-height` from `<img>` makes the image appear but overflow the sides of the screen and the navigation bar beneath, which is also not what I want. How can I properly accomplish this task using CSS rather than lengthy JavaScript?

Comment: Hard to picture what your issue is without seeing it. Do you have the option to use background images? This sounds like what `background-size: cover;` is for.

Comment: @KurtEmch The current version (using JavaScript resize) is live at http://artmonitors.com/slideshow, or it will be when I get home from work (I just changed today from using JS for the fade-in fade-out to using CSS for it). The problem with `cover` is that it cuts off part of the image, which I absolutely do not want.

Comment: So `background-size: contain;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this layout structure hits all of your requirements. There are three images of varying size in here I took the opacity down so you can see how they all scale together.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>

        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .images {
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
        }
    .image {
        position: absolute; 

        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;

        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

        opacity: 0.5;

    }
    .image-container {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

.footer {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: auto;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="images">
            <div class="image-container">
                <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1000/425)"></div>
                <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/640/1000)"></div>
                <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/800/800)"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">Content</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This mostly works, with one caveat. It uses `background-image=url()` instead of `src=`, which is causing a problem. Any idea how to use this for urls that happen to contain the apostrophe character `'`? The typical `&apos;` or `&#39;` substitutions will not work, and I've had problems with that before.

Comment: Never mind, figured it out. Just encase the url in double-quotes, works even if injecting it via JavaScript.